# how to scroll the layout above listview like facebook

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I want to scroll the layout am using above the list view to scroll with it when i scroll down.
Like Facebook scrolls the cover when we scroll on out profile.  I have tried placing them into relative output and using scroll view but unfortunately nothing works. Despite the fact that there are many questions similar to this on stackoverflow none of them has been answered authentically.

**Example layout :**

```
<LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/layout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:background="#000000">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/profilefraglayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:background="#000000">
            </LinearLayout>
            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
            </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear of what type of effect you want.  Could you please attach an image or GIF demonstrating your desired result?

Comment: You must use action bar pull to refresh lib. Regards

Comment: if you want to see the demonstration just open your facebook app and notice what facebook app does to the facebook cover and display picture when you scroll down to see your status list and posts (listview).

Answer (score 0):

use [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
>

   <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/custom_layout" />

</ScrollView>

<ListView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can control the size of the two layout by android:layout_weight

Comment: This is not working correctly. It's getting stuck and the scroll isn't smooth. There must be a right way to do this.

Comment: do you mean somthing like this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar/master/graphics/notboringab.gif)

Comment: Yes like this. But this is changing it into action bar when scrolled. How can i do this ? Maybe it will explain how can i do that.

Comment: it's a bit different what i want but this would also help if explained... i have found this on github but i can't implement it if its not explained. How did he manage to scroll the upper layout ?

Comment: check out [link](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll) , [link](https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager) , [link](http://javatechig.com/android/listview-header-parallax-in-android) , [link](http://androiddhina.blogspot.in/2015/08/listview-header-parallax-with-sticky-view-in-android.html) and search for parallax view/scroll there're different libraries for that

Comment: in these examples its making it an actionbar. i just want it to scroll with listview like a simple layout does  without listview.

Comment: it's the same concept you just control the header from code when scroll down to collapse it [link](http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/10/04/making-that-google-plus-profile-screen/)